# Definir Conexão Dinamicamente no Model Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5

Vi que posso usar diferentes conexões para meus models definindo da seguinte forma:

```
class Aparelho extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'minha_conexao';
    protected $table = 'aparelhos';
}
```

Mas como posso definir isso dinamicamente? Tipo isso aqui: (Que não funciona)

```
class Aparelho extends Model
{
    protected $connection = Auth::user()->conexao;
    protected $table = 'aparelhos';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, encontrei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21941911/5650313) no SO em inglês que me ajudou a solucionar isso da seguinte forma:

```
class Aparelho extends Model
{
    protected $connection;

    function __construct()
    {
        return $this->connection = Auth::user()->conexao;
    }

    protected $table = 'aparelhos';
}
```